# Errors: {"obj.overallCount":[{"msg":["error.path.missing"],"args":[]}]}

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I am trying to convert the json in to Data class. It is showing an error

> Errors:
>   {"obj.overallCount":[{"msg":["error.path.missing"],"args":[]}]}

, I am not being able to figure out the problem. Looking for experts' help:

---

```
case class Count(count:Long)
  case class OverallCount(overallCount:List[Count])

    "JsonTest" should "show result" in {
      Future {


        import play.api.libs.json._

        implicit val count = Json.reads[Count]
        implicit val ovc = Json.reads[OverallCount]

        val jsonString: JsValue = Json.parse(
          """{"countOverall":[{"count":4}]}"""
        )


        val residentFromJson: JsResult[OverallCount] = Json.fromJson[OverallCount](jsonString)


        residentFromJson match {
          case JsSuccess(r: OverallCount, path: JsPath) => Console.println("overallCount: " + r.overallCount)
          case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toJson(e).toString())
        }


        succeed
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Either replace

  ```
  val jsonString: JsValue = Json.parse(
    """{"countOverall":[{"count":4}]}"""
  )
  ```

  with

  ```
  val jsonString: JsValue = Json.parse(
    """{"overallCount":[{"count":4}]}"""
  )
  ```
- or replace

  ```
  case class OverallCount(overallCount: List[Count])
  ```

  with

  ```
  case class OverallCount(countOverall: List[Count])
  ```